# Python, combining data as a matching part of two files using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, key, key-value

**Input1:**

```
Aa  Ab,Ac,Information1
Ba  Bb,Bc,Information2
Ca  Cb,Cc,Information3
```

**Input2:**

```
ID 
A1
A2 information3
A3 asdfasdf
A3 vlkmgoie
//
ID
A1
A2 information2
A3 opjnbiube
A3 plwikjnd
//
```

**Expected output:**

```
>Aa,Ab,Ac,Information1

>Ba,Bb,Bc,Information2
A3 opjnbiube
A3 plwikjnd
>Ca,Cb,Cc,Information3
A3 asdfasdf
A3 vlkmgoie
```

**Code:**

```
dictionary = {}
with open(input_file1, 'r') as input1:
    for line in input1:
        replaced_line = '>' + line.replace('\t', ',').strip()
        id = replaced_line.strip().split(',')[-1]
        dictionary[id] = id


with open(input_file2, 'r') as input2:
    for block in input2.read().split('//'): 
        
        for k in dictionary.keys():
            keys_from_id = k

            if keys_from_id in block:
```

First, I extracted only the information at the end of input_file1. Second, blocks(units) were made based on '//' in Input_file2. In this situation, if blocks from input_file2 contain information extracted from input_file1, I want to write the contents of a part of the block below each line of input_file1 like 'Expected output'. So, my question is how can I save the information extracted from input_file1 as a dictionary by matching the block contents of input_file2?

Answer (score 1):

You could do as follows:

```
import re

s1 = "Aa  Ab,Ac,Information1\nBa  Bb,Bc,Information2\nCa  Cb,Cc,Information3"
s2 = "ID\nA1\nA2 information3\nA3 asdfasdf\nA3 vlkmgoi\n//\nID\nA1\nA2 information2\nA3 opjnbiube\nA3 plwikjnd//"

pattern = re.compile("(information\d+)(.*)", re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)

d1 = {x[-1]:re.sub("[ ]+", ",", ",".join(x)) for x in list(map(lambda x:x.split(","), s1.split("\n")))}
d2 = {x[0][0].capitalize(): x[0][1].strip().split("\n") for x in map(lambda x: pattern.findall(x), s2.split("//")) if len(x) == 1}

for k, v in d1.items():
    print(f'>{v}')
    print("\n".join(d2.get(k, "")))
```